# Monitors get No Signal when computer is asleep and turn off instead of going into stand by

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Ok, so I just moved and after moving I'm having a weird issue after setting my desktop back up.  I can't even think of where I might look to resolve this so figured I'd see if anyone else has an idea.  Before I moved, I ran my 3 monitors with one HDMI and two DVI connections.  Since moving I decided to move my computer elsewhere so I don't hear the fan noise as much (even with really high quality low noise fans it's still a persistent annoying background noise to me lol), so I got some 15 foot flat flexible HDMI cables to run to all 3 monitors.

When I'm done using my computer I always put it to sleep so that I can wake it with the keyboard or mouse without having to hit the power button.  When I do that now with the new setup, instead of the monitors going into stand by mode like they used to, they show No Signal and eventually power off completely.  If I wake the computer up and manually turn the monitors back on, everything is fine.  So this is not a bug with the computer not waking up properly.

I'm going to test a different HDMI cable tonight in case it's something to do with these new HDMI cables (although I'm not sure what about a cable could cause this behavior), but figured I'd also post here and see if anyone else had some ideas of what might cause this behavior.

A few hardware specs that might be relevant:

Video Card: Geforce GTX 970

Monitors: 3x LG 27EA63V-P 27" IPS monitors (pretty sure this is the right model number, been a while since I bought them)

Motherboard: Asus P9X79 Deluxe

Comment: Try going to the Windows Control Panel > Hardware and sound. Check your settings to see what's happening when you put your computer to sleep. Otherwise, it could be an HDMI cable that's not working properly, or Windows does not support a connection with your HDMI cables while your computer is sleeping. When you disengage the sleep mode on your computer, your monitors should turn back on anyways.

Comment: I will look into it tonight just to be sure, but it was working before I moved so not sure how a windows setting would've changed to cause it.  But as for the second part, no the monitors will not turn back on because they do not go into low power stand by mode, they actually power off.  The No Signal message never used to show on the monitor when I put the computer to sleep, they would just go black and then into stand by.  Now No Signal displays like it does if you unplug the hdmi cable completely, and stays there for a few minutes until the monitor turns itself completely off.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, well I have confirmed that the problem is the HDMI cables.  Don't know what it is about the new HDMI cables that causes that but as soon as I use a different HDMI cable on one of the monitors, no more problems with that monitor.

Guess I'll have to take these HDMI cables back and try something different.  It's more expensive but maybe I'll get a display port hub since my graphics card has a displayport 1.2 and try that instead.  Would only require me to run one long wire instead of 3 then at least.